Vscode IntelliSense not working for C/C++ whatever I do
I can't get Vscode to syntax-highlight or complete any C/C++ code.

I'm on the latest Vscode (1.90.1 as of writing).
C/C++ and C/C++ Extension pack (latest, non-insider versions) is installed and enabled.
I have clang installed and working.
Trying to follow Vscode's official documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

I create a folder, opened it using code /path/to/my/folder, have an empty CPP file. I'm trying exactly what the docs say, line by line. I've even pasted the exact code from the docs yet it's recognized as "Plain Text" and no completion nor coloring work:




Above is what my Vscode environment looks like, whereas Microsoft's documentation has nicely syntax highlighted, code-completing C/C++ file with the exact same steps that I did. In my instance, I don't even see C or C++ in list of languages to pick from and it is recognized as "Plain Text".
Here is my settings.json:

{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "editor.codeLens": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "window.title": "${activeFolderShort}/${activeEditorShort} (${activeFolderLong})",
    "debug.console.fontSize": 10,
    "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "editor.fastScrollSensitivity": 3,
    "typescript.tsserver.trace": "verbose",
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default",
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Monokai]": {
            "keywords": "#ff4a5f",
            "functions": "#99ff88",
            "comments": "#80a090",
            "textMateRules": [
               
                {
                    "scope": "keyword.operator",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#ffaa66"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "entity.name.tag",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#ff3377",
                        "fontStyle": "bold"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#44e855",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations":{

        "[Monokai]": {
            "editorIndentGuide.background1": "#383838",
            "editor.background": "#20201e",
            "statusBar.background" : "#1A1A1A",
            "statusBar.noFolderBackground" : "#212121",
            "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#263238",
        },
       
      },
      "task.slowProviderWarning": [
        "typescript"
      ],
      "update.mode": "manual",
      "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
      "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 1000,
      "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 9,
      "editor.fontSize": 8,
      "editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false,
      "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 80,
      "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
      "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto",
      "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDeclarations": "goto",
      "editor.gotoLocation.multipleImplementations": "goto",
      "editor.gotoLocation.multipleReferences": "goto",
      "editor.gotoLocation.multipleTypeDefinitions": "goto",
      "apc.activityBar": {
        "size": 42,
        "itemMargin": 2
      },
      "apc.sidebar.titlebar": {
        "fontSize": 10
      },
      "apc.header": {
        "fontSize": 10,
        "height": 24,
      },
      "apc.stylesheet": {
        ".explorer-viewlet .mac": "font-size: 11px",
        ".debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench.mac .debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench.mac .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression":
          "font-size: 10px !important",
        ".part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .tabs-container>.tab, .tabs-and-actions-container": "height: 28px !important",
        ".monaco-icon-label": "font-size: 8pt",
        ".monaco-editor, .monaco-editor-background, .monaco-editor .inputarea.ime-input": "background-color: #1c1e1c"
      },
      "apc.listRow": {
        "height": 18
      },
      "customizeUI.fontSizeMap": {
          "window-title": "10px", // Window title font when using custom titlebar
          "tab-title": "11px",    // Used for editor tab titles
      },
      "customizeUI.listRowHeight": 18,
      "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
          ".explorer-viewlet .mac": "font-size: 11px",
          ".debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench.mac .debug-viewlet .monaco-list-row .expression, body.row-height-lte20 .monaco-workbench.mac .debug-hover-widget .monaco-list-row .expression":
            "font-size: 10px !important",
          ".part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .tabs-container>.tab, .tabs-and-actions-container": "height: 28px !important",
          ".monaco-icon-label": "font-size: 8pt",
          ".monaco-editor, .monaco-editor-background, .monaco-editor .inputarea.ime-input": "background-color: #1c1e1c"
      },
      "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
      "terminal.integrated.lineHeight": 0.8,
      "color-highlight.languages": [
        "*"
      ],
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "debug.javascript.suggestPrettyPrinting": false,
    "workbench.editor.decorations.badges": false,
    "explorer.decorations.badges": false,
    "react-native-tools.showUserTips": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "react-native-tools.networkInspector.consoleLogsColorTheme": "Dark",
    "debug.console.wordWrap": false,
    "workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
        "‘": true,
        "’": true
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "solidity.validationDelay": 500,
    "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true,
    "workbench.settings.enableNaturalLanguageSearch": false,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "window.restoreWindows": "all",
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.includeStrings": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    },
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.css": "tailwindcss"
    },
    "eslint.runtime": "node",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "workbench.editor.empty.hint": "hidden",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always",
    "solidity.telemetry": false,
    "cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification": false

}


Please note that C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine setting wasn't there and it still wasn't working, I've added while trying to find a solution but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
I've also tried disabling all the extensions except C/C++ (and, in another instance, in addition to C/C++ also C/C++ Extension Pack) and restarting Vscode, but nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong?

Can you show your settings.json? Maybe you customized the default language for .cpp files. You can also try disabling all extensions except for the C/C++ one.

Agreed with point of @HolyBlackCat about disabling all extensions except the C/C++ one. If you want to see sample settings.json and other config files, I've made a blog about this. Setup Guide for C/C++ Programming on VSCode

@Raildex this is on a mac, there's  no VS C++ compiler for mac. They'd need to use the xcode build tools

@Raildex Moreover, basic highlighting should work without any compiler. And they don't specifically need MSVC, any compiler is fine.

I would recommend not using intellisense at all.

@HolyBlackCat please see my updated question. I've added settings.json and disabled all the other extensions yet the same.

@UsmanMehmood please see my updated question. I've disabled all the other extensions yet the same.

@user12002570 your comment doesn't add anything to the solution.

@CanPoyrazoğlu That's why it was posted as a comment not an answer. It is not an answer and nor supposed to be.

Does it work if you manually switch to C++ mode by clicking that "plain text" button in the corner?

@HolyBlackCat I cannot. there is no "C" or "C++" in the language list in the first place. the third screenshot in the question shows a list of languages when I click "Plain Text" to bring the language picker.

@user12002570 that doesn't add anything useful as a comment too. anyway, I've solved the issue and IntelliSense works perfectly now.

@CanPoyrazoğlu Good to hear that you solved your problem.

I solved the problem by removing my ~/Library/Application Support/Code and ~/.vscode/extensions directories (I first tried the latter alone but didn't work, then I also removed the former). I don't know what was causing the issue, but I backed up my settings.json from there, deleted everything, restarted Vscode, put settings.json back, restarted Vscode, installed C/C++ extension (as all extensions also got deleted), and the issue got fixed. I can now see C++ in the language list and IntelliSense works perfectly.

VSC has some hidden extensions installed by default, they are responsible e.g. for this basic C/C++ syntax highlighting. You can see them in the extension marketplace gui if you search for @builtin.

@HolyBlackCat thank you! I'll check them out. Perhaps, for whatever reason, that got corrupted and nuking the whole folder recreated them properly. since I've been using Vscode 7+ years and never purged anything, something might have got corrupted somewhere along the way.
